# How can I convert strings in angle brackets to uppercase on MacOS?

Tags: macos, sed, substitution, gnu-sed

I am working in MacOS 10.12 and I have 100 files such as this:

```
My file <structure_is> like this <and_maybe_like> this,
but not quite like this.
But there might be <stuff> like this, too.
```

I have been trying to convert all of the items in <> to uppercase to see the file look like this:

```
My file <STRUCTURE_IS> like this <AND_MAYBE_LIKE> this,
but not quite like this.
But there might be <STUFF> like this, too.
```

I tried using:

```
find . -name "\*" | xargs sed 's/\<([a-z_][^>]*)\>/\U&/g'
```

I have also tried using gsed (home-brew):

```
find . -name "\*" | xargs gsed 's/\<([a-z_][^>]*)\>/\U&/g'
```

But all I get out is the contents of the files themselves to stdout.

How do I do this?

Kindest regards!

Answer (score 1):

This works on Linux: `sed 's/<[^>]*>/\U&/g' file`

I don't know if `\U` is GNU sed only.

Alternately, perl:

```
perl -pe 's/<.*?>/\U$&/g' file
```

Comment: Yes it is. Try `sed --posix ...`.

Answer (score 0):

`<` in a regexp is a literal `<` while `\<` in GNU sed at least is a word delimiter escape sequence. So, just change your `\<`to `<` and `\>` to `>` and your `gsed` script would work fine.

Never escape a character unless you KNOW what you're doing. If you want a literal character `c` and don't know if you need to escape it or not then you're safer using `[c]` than `\c` because at least the former can't turn it into a regexp metacharacter.